# How can I shorten a string of colours using recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

I am writing a recursive solution to try and solve:
https://www.codewars.com/kata/5a25ac6ac5e284cfbe000111/train/python

The idea is that we are given a long string consisting of three colours R,B,G ; and we need to reduce this string to a single character.

The way we reduce it is if we have two consecutive colours `RR->R, GG->G, BB->B`, otherwise, if we have two different colours, we will return the third colour, i.e. `RG->B or RB->G`, etc

Here is my recursive solution so far:

```
def triangle(colours):
    color_combi= {"RR":"R","GG":"G","BB":"B"
                 "RG":"B", "GR":"B", "GB":"R", "BG":"R", 
                  "BR":"G","RB":"G"}
    
    def reduce_string(col): 
        if len(col) ==1: 
            return col 
    
    return reduce_string(colours)
```

I am not sure if it is possible to solve this problem using recursion but in my mind it seem like a question that can be solved by recursion. However, I can't quite write code for the recursive relation- any ideas how to do so?

In theory I know what I want to do- for every two index, I will call on the key in my dictionary to return a single value- and will continue to do so until we hit the base case, then simply return the remaining character!

Comment: It's possible, but why use recursion? Just write a loop and avoid blowing the call stack and incurring overhead, as well as making the code harder to write and understand. Not all problems are well-suited for recursion, especially ones that only reduce the problem size by 1 per call (linear).

Comment: How would you process the string 'RRG'? How do you choose between `'RRG' -> 'RG' -> 'B'` and `'RRG' -> 'RB' -> 'G'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `zip` with slices is an easy way to iterate over sets of adjacent elements in a list.

For a recursive solution where each function call goes one row down the triangle I might do:

```
>>> def color_triangle(row: str) -> str:
...     if len(row) == 1:
...         return row
...     return color_triangle(''.join(
...         c1 if c1 == c2 else next(
...             c3 for c3 in ('R', 'G', 'B') 
                if c3 not in (c1, c2)
...         )
...         for c1, c2 in zip(row, row[1:])
...     ))
...
>>> color_triangle("RRGBRGBB")
'G'
```

This doesn't have any benefits over the equivalent iterative solution though, and the iterative solution takes up less space (since it only keeps one copy of `row` in memory):

```
>>> def color_triangle(row: str) -> str:
...     while len(row) > 1:
...         row = color_triangle(''.join(
...             c1 if c1 == c2 else next(
...                 c3 for c3 in ('R', 'G', 'B') 
                    if c3 not in (c1, c2)
...             )
...             for c1, c2 in zip(row, row[1:])
...         ))
...     return row
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is simple iterative solution. It first converts the letters to 1, 2, and 3 respectively, as then it becomes a simple XOR job.

```
def triangle(row):
    row = ["-RGB".index(color) for color in row]
    for n in range(len(row) - 1, 0, -1):
        for j in range(n):
            row[j] = (row[j] ^ row[j+1]) or row[j]
    return "-RGB"[row[0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:

```
def triangle(colours):
    color_combi = {"RR": "R", "GG": "G", "BB": "B", "RG":"B", "GR": "B", "GB": "R", "BG": "R","BR": "G", "RB": "G"}

    def reduce_string(col):
        output = ""
        if len(col) == 1:
            return col

        for i in range(0, len(col)-1):
            temp = col[i] + col[i + 1]
            output += color_combi[temp]

        return reduce_string(output)

    return reduce_string(colours)
```